# Microsoft Surface Pro (2017) remap volume UP/DOWN keys on Type Cover

Tags: microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro, sharpkeys

I have a Microsoft Surface Pro 2017.

Because volume UP/DOWN buttons are already there on top of the screen next to power button...

[image]

So I want to remap the volume UP/DOWN keys on the Type Cover.

[image]

I already used Sharpkeys to remap some of my keys on the Type Cover.

What are the Sharpkey codes for Volume Up/Down on the Type Cover?

If I can't use Sharpkeys, what should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to do this and I started messing with Sharpkeys. That was a dead-end.
I'm now using AutoHotKey to turn them into arrow keys with:

```
#NoEnv ; Recommended for compatibility with 
AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input ; Recommended for new scripts.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir% ; Ensures consistent starting directory.

#IfWinActive
  Volume_Down::Send {Right}
  Volume_Up::Send {Left}
```

(Derived from [medium.com](https://medium.com/@docky/how-to-use-volume-as-an-alt-button-on-the-surface-pro-4-b0d13ee9638))